# Winrt GridView Virtualization

Tags: windows-runtime, virtualization

I've been having multiple problems trying to show `GridViewItems` in a `GridView` in different layouts. Basically EVERYTHING kills virtualization. If we use a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` virutalizaiton is gone, if we use the built in grouping functionality virtualizaiton is also gone. So far the only solution:

[Only Solution](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/solving-winrt-xaml-gridview)

But that doesn't really cut it because it changes the design so much. As I said, the basic problem is that pretty much any small layout change you make on the `GridView` breaks virtualization. Has anyone found a good way to avoid this problem when changing a `GridView` or has everybody just had to stick with how the `GridView` looks by default?

Oh, another thing. Unfortunately WinRT doesn't allow us to create our custom virutalized panel because the `VirtualizingStackPanel` constructor is `protected` (or `private`, can't remember correctly). If you can give some information about this that would be great too =).

Thanks!

Comment: if you found solution, provide it, please.

Comment: @jimpanzer Never found a solution. I'm working on a different project now.

Answer (score 1):

anytime you change the panel to a VariableSizedWrapGrid, or you use Grouping on your gridview, the virutalization it's gone. I posted in Uservoice about that, in order to support virtualization with the VariableSizedWrapGrid

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4333881-make-variablesizedwrapgrid-virtualizing-